# How to dump the headers of IOKit in iOS6?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, iphone-privateapi

The private framework headers dumped by kennytm have been widely used.But with the upgrade of iOS, the headers have changed some.Now from `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/IOKit` we can dump nothing useful as below. How can we dump the headers of iOS6?
Thank you for your help!

```
/*
 *     Generated by class-dump 3.4 (64 bit).
 *
 *     class-dump is Copyright (C) 1997-1998, 2000-2001, 2004-2012 by Steve Nygard.
 */

#pragma mark -

/*
 * File: IOKit
 * UUID: A98BA9FE-FC73-33E4-A5A9-169198848C62
 * Arch: armv7
 *       Current version: 275.0.0, Compatibility version: 1.0.0
 *       Source version: 756.35.0.0.0
 *       Minimum iOS version: 6.1.0
 *       SDK version: 6.1.0
 *
 */

//
// This file does not contain any Objective-C runtime information.
//
```

Comment: I believe you should point it to the binary file (instead of framework dir). So, it will be IOKit.framework/IOKit or something like that.

Comment: Yes, I have tried that, I pointed to the binary file IOKit inside IOKit.framework but dumped nothing useful.

Answer (score 2):

Suge - If you copy UIKit in the same directory as class-dump and issue command "class-dump -H UIKit", you would be able to see lot of header files generated in same directory. The reason you don't see for IOKit, is because its bit low level and it has all C style functions.

Use otool -tV IOKit > sample.txt and you will get signature of all functions and its disassembly.

Personally I use Hopper Disassembler as Victor Ronin had suggested in earlier posts.

Hope this helps.